# AS3 dispatching contentLoaderInfo

Tags: actionscript-3

I wish to know how to dispatch the **contentLoaderInfo** of external SWF to be usable on other frame where the original swf loaded instead. It would like to expand the loaded SWF frame in the timeline.

If I load the SWF on frame 1, I wish control it on frame 2 or 3 etc. without reload it anymore.

Please help

Comment: The loaded content is not controlled by frames. If you have, like, 1000 frames on your main timeline, and then **addChild(...)** a **Loader** instance (actually, any object created by script and not controlled by the timeline design) that loads some external **SWF**, it will stay visible and accessible through all 1000 frames. However, if you attach the new object to other container that does not exist through these 1000 frames, then the attached content will perish along with its container.

Comment: Alright, the problem when the loaded swf containing sound, it will be always getting reload once re-entering the swf frame after left it. It traced multiple-sound (getting louder) because I back to **addChild** without **removeChild** on left it.

Comment: If I holding on the app seems like fine. But it consumes large CPU memory more and more then getting slower to run.

Comment: I would like to load it once to keep the memory usage stable

Comment: Then load it once, the problem seems to be that you don't check if you've already loaded the thing, and it loads over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Make an actionscript file called Global.as in your project root like this:

```
package {
    public class Global {
        public static var externalSWF:DisplayObject;
    }
}
```

On frame 1, add this code at the top:

```
import Global;
```

And later where you have the loader for this SWF, add this code to save the loaded swf into the global variable you created.

```
Global.externalSWF = loader.content;
```

And finally, in frame 2, and 3 you can re-use your loaded SWF using again an import statement at the top of the file and then addChild like so:

```
import Global;

addChild(Global.externalSWF);
```